# How would I do this type of for loop in ruby?

Tags: ruby, for-loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < 200000; i += 50){
    // Do Stuff
}
```

The only way I can think to do it is to do the following

```
arr = [0,50,100,...,200000]
arr.each do |i|
    // Do Stuff
end
```

If that is in fact the only way. How could you build that array quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(0..200000).step(50) do |i|
  # Do stuff
end
```

You can look at the [full documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-step).

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I just posted another way to do this, but, this is way more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
(0...200000).step(50) do |i|
  # Do stuff
end
```